# How to overlap inner circle with outer circle for react native progress indicator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native-progress to build a progress circle app.

Can we make the inner circle to appear exactly on the outer circle of this progress indicator

I have edited radius property and but unable to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you please share your example with https://snack.expo.io/ .

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@malliswari/progresscircle

Comment: We are using SVG shape circle from ART Library it seems to be confusing as to how to set the radius to be same for inner and outer circle for circular progress indicator implemented using react-native-progress. Can you please assist me?